# Adding favorites in list view using shared preferences

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

My app has a lost view and every listitem has a favorite button which when clicked should save the list item and save it in shared preferences. All the favorites list items should be displayed in another my favorites activity and when the list item from my favorites activity is long press it should be removed from favorites. When the favorites button is clicked it should turn dark indicating its added to favorites . in my case
1) when list item is added to favorites the favorites button turn dark but when the activity is closed and reopened the button is no longer dark
2)the list items are getting added to my favorites activity but on long press are not getting removed

**sharedpreference.java**

```
public class SharedPreference
{

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MY_APP";
public static final String FAVORITES = "code_Favorite";

public SharedPreference(){
    super();
}

public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<CodeList> favorites){
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

    editor.commit();
}

public void addFavorite(Context context, CodeList code){
    List<CodeList> favorites = getFavorites(context);

    if(favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        favorites.add(code);
        saveFavorites(context,favorites);
}

public void removeFavorite(Context context, CodeList code) {
    ArrayList<CodeList> favorites = getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        favorites.remove(code);
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
        }
    }


public ArrayList<CodeList> getFavorites(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    List<CodeList> favorites;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CodeList[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                                                CodeList[].class);

        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList<CodeList>(favorites);
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList<CodeList>) favorites;
}

}
```

**my base adapter**

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(view == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beg_list_item,null);
        holder.listHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.beg_list_itemTextView);
    //  holder.listHash = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_hashtags);
        holder.alphabetList = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.beg_list_itemImageView);
        holder.favoriteImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favbtn);
        view.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        CodeList code = (CodeList) getItem(position);
        holder.listHeading.setText(codeList.get(position).getListHeading());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(codeList.get(position).getAlphabetimg(),
                                holder.alphabetList);
    //  holder.listHash.setText(codeList.get(position).getListHashTags());                      

    if (checkFavoriteItem(code)) {
        holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
        holder.favoriteImg.setTag("yes");
    } else {
        holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
        holder.favoriteImg.setTag("no");
    }

            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);

                    //intent.putExtra("listheading",
                    //       (codeList.get(position).getListHeading()));
                    //intent.putExtra("alphabetimg",
                    //              (codeList.get(position).getAlphabetimg()));

                    intent.putExtra("demovideo",
                                    (codeList.get(position).getDailogdemovideo()));

                    intent.putExtra("download",
                                    (codeList.get(position).getDownloadCode()));

                    // Start SingleItemView Class
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });



            final ImageView favoritesbutton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

            favoritesbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    String tag = favoritesbutton.getTag().toString();

                    if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                        shrdPrefence.addFavorite(context, codeList.get(position));

                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.fav_added, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        favoritesbutton.setTag("yes");
                        favoritesbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
                    }else{
                        shrdPrefence.removeFavorite(context, codeList.get(position));
                        favoritesbutton.setTag("no");
                        favoritesbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.fav_removed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });


    return view;
}

//Checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences*/
public boolean checkFavoriteItem(CodeList checkCode) {
    boolean check = false;
    List<CodeList> favorites = shrdPrefence.getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        for (CodeList code : favorites) {
            if (code.equals(checkCode)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}


public void add(CodeList code) {

    codeList.add(code);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void remove(CodeList code) {

    codeList.remove(code);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**my favorite..java**

```
    public class MyFavActivity extends Activity
    {
    SharedPreference shrdPrfence;
    List<CodeList> favorites;

    FinalAdapter fnlAdpter;
    Context context = this.context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fav_layout);

        shrdPrfence = new SharedPreference();
        favorites = shrdPrfence.getFavorites(MyFavActivity.this);

        if(favorites == null){
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyFavActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.nofav_title);
            dialog.show();
        }else{
            if(favorites.size() == 0){
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyFavActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.nofav_title);
                dialog.show();
            }

            ListView favList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fav_layoutListView);

            if(favorites != null){
                fnlAdpter = new FinalAdapter(MyFavActivity.this, favorites);
                favList.setAdapter(fnlAdpter);

                favList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                                                int position, long arg3) {

                        }
                    });





                favList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                            ImageView button = (ImageView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

                            String tag = button.getTag().toString();
                            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                                shrdPrfence.addFavorite(MyFavActivity.this,
                                                             favorites.get(position));
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    MyFavActivity.this,
                                        R.string.fav_added,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                button.setTag("yes");
                                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
                            } else {
                                shrdPrfence.removeFavorite(MyFavActivity.this,
                                                                favorites.get(position));
                                button.setTag("no");
                                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
                                fnlAdpter.remove(favorites.get(position));
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    MyFavActivity.this,
                                        R.string.fav_removed,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
        }

   }
```

**codelist.java**
    public class CodeList
{

```
private String description;


private String dailogdemovideo;

private String downloadCode;


public void setDailogdemovideo(String dailogdemovideo)
{
    this.dailogdemovideo = dailogdemovideo;
}

public String getDailogdemovideo()
{
    return dailogdemovideo;
}
public void setDownloadCode(String downloadCode)
{
    this.downloadCode = downloadCode;
}

public String getDownloadCode()
{
    return downloadCode;
}



public void setDescription(String description)
{
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}



    }
```

Comment: Can you show CodeList source? You use equals, but this will not work without overriding equals (and hashCode())

Comment: @aelimill Didn't understand what you said. Can you please be more specific. Thank you

Comment: In Java comparing two objects via "equals method" works only when they reference the same object. Your CodeList objects are recreated each time they returned from gson, so comparing them via equals is useless unless you override "equals method" in your CodeList class.

Comment: @aelimill Ohk understood I will post my code list

Comment: @aelimill Posted the codelist code. Have a look. By the way I use baseadapter

Comment: So you didn't override equals, so because of that your code do not work. If  you do not have the unique property like id that you can compare and distinguish to CodeList (downloadCode, maybe?), you should override equals and hashcode methods. If you use Android Studio just generate those methods https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generate-equals-and-hashcode-wizard.html

Comment: @aelimill I use aide in ANDROID

Comment: @aelimill Thanks a lot. It helped me so much. Got stuck on this problem for weeks.Followed your advice and its working. Don't know how to thank you more